# Тире после слова "я"

Tags: пунктуация

Я -- художник, я -- так вижу.

или

Я -- художник, я так вижу.

И вообще, в каком случае нужно ставить тире после "я"? Можно объяснить на примере фразы "я художник".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Постановка тире между подлежащим  и составным именным сказуемом во многом корректируется интонацией, а именно наличием паузы. Очень часто это авторская интонация. На вопрос "Вы кто?" - можно ответить: "Я художник". Это основная форма для варианта "местоимение в роли подлежащего - существительное в роли сказуемого". В стихотворных текстах местоимение в роли подлежащего  часто выделяется паузой, при этом на него падает интонационное ударение.В то же время наличие паузы (и тире) следует проверять по интонации всего предложения в целом. Нет паузы и тире, если интонационное ударение падает на сказуемое.
Примеры: 
Я странник убогий. Я честный человек и никогда не говорю комплименты. Мы хозяева нашей природы, и она для нас кладовая солнца. Я ужасно рада, что ты мой брат. Не правда ли, что мы краса долины всей? Я свет весны, а ты усталый холод. Я златоцвет, который вечно молод, а ты песок на мертвых берегах. Он  порча, он чума, он  язва здешних мест.НО:    Я –  северный ваш друг и брат!  Ты – вечности заложник у времени в плену. Все мы – гроздья винограда золотого лета.     Я – внезапный излом, я – играющий гром, я – прозрачный ручей, я – для всех и ничей!

Наша пунктуация основана на трех принципах: семантическом, грамматическом и интонационном.Между собой эти принципы связаны следующим образом:семантический принцип - это содержание предложения, а грамматический и интонационный принцип - это его форма.К сожалению, об интонационном принципе у нас вспоминают не часто,  при этом трактуют его очень странно, например говорят об интонационном тире. Но любое тире является интонационным, так как ставится на месте паузы. А логическое выделение слова - это усиленное интонационное ударение. С помощью интонации поставленная задача решается  элементарно просто, без длинных рассуждений, а решение более верное, так как соответствует правильному прочтению предложения.К примеру, в параллельных конструкциях не всегда ставится тире.

Answer (score 10):

Если подлежащее выражено личным местоимением, а сказуемое – существительным в именительном падеже, тире ставится в следующих случаях:

```
а) при логическом выделении местоимения:
Она – виновница того превращения. (И.А. Гончаров. Обломов)
Ты – лестница в большом, туманном доме. (В.В. Набоков. Лестница)

б) при противопоставлении:
Я жажду и алчу, а ты – пустоцвет,
И встреча с тобой безотрадней гранита.
(Б.Л. Пастернак. Чудо)
Вот мы – соучастники сборищ.
Вот Анна – сообщник природы...
(Б.А. Ахмадулина. Анне Каландадзе)

в) при обратном порядке слов:
Лебедь тут, вздохнув глубоко,
Молвила: «Зачем далеко?
Знай, близка судьба твоя,
Ведь царевна эта – я».
(А.С. Пушкин. Сказка о царе Салтане)

г) при структурном параллелизме частей предложения:
Он весь – дитя добра и света,
Он весь – свободы торжество!
(А.А. Блок. О, я хочу безумно жить!)
```

[Все случаи постановки тире. Повторение](http://rus.1september.ru/articlef.php?ID=200202402)

*Я — художник, я так вижу.* После первого *Я* тире возможно для логического подчёркивания. Второе тире нежелательно, здесь не тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, не синтаксический параллелизм, оно явно интонационное, хотя тоже возможно. Иногда оно ставится для указания места распадения простого предложения на две словесные группы, если другими знаками препинания или порядком слов это не может быть выражено, например:
*Я вас спрашиваю: рабочим – нужно платить?*(Чехов)

[ПРАВИЛА РУССКОЙ ОРФОГРАФИИ И ПУНКТУАЦИИ (1956)](http://gramota.ru/spravka/rules/?rub=tire)

Но такое распадение чаще наблюдается при пропуске какого-нибудь члена предложения (почему ставящееся в этом случае тире называется эллиптическим), например:

*Пусторослеву за верную службу – чижовскую усадьбу, а Чижова – в Сибирь навечно.*
В Вашем примере пропуска члена предложения нет, а насчёт логического подчёркивания — это зависит от автора.

Comment: Люсенька, вернитесь, придите спасать! Вы очень нужны: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/453837/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%9b%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5/453848?noredirect=1#comment464555_453848

Comment: @Людмилаи https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/453841/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%bc%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%88%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2-%d1%87%d1%83%d0%b6%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%bc%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d1%8c/453858#453858

Answer (score -1):

А не является ли это правило (не ставить тире) неверным искажением языка? Какую-то тут паузу ищем, чтобы поставить. Это же потерянный глагол *есть*, потерянный глагол меняем на тире. Я есть художник. Я — художник.  В «импортных» языках этот глагол остался, am, suis, bin. И у нас он был: "Аз есмь". По мне, так ставить тире везде между местоимением и существительным было бы нормально.

Comment: *Он неплохой художник. Он немного странный парень.* и т.п. — Вы настаиваете на тире во всех этих предложениях только потому, что в английском есть глагол *is*, а у нас был глагол *есмь*?