# Колокольчик символизирует воскрешение Лазаря, - не воскресение?

Tags: паронимы

> «Вот – колокольчик. Такой колокольчик всегда пригодится! Вы, вообще,
>   знаете, что он символизирует? Воскрешение Лазаря! Вы историк – и не
>   знаете! Ай-яй-яй! Любой сербский школьник вам об этом расскажет, если,
>   конечно, в его школе хорошо преподают русский!»

Передана прямая речь какого-то чокнутого сельского учителя, одаряющего всякой всячиной всех подряд.

Что-то смущает меня **символ воскрешения**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Галина, Ваше восприятие выдаёт советское воспитание, там воскрешение и воскресение не различались, вот Большой словарь русских поговорок. — М: Олма Медиа Групп. В. М. Мокиенко, Т. Г. Никитина. 2007:

> Воскресение (воскрешение) святого Лазаря Книжн. Устар. Шутл. 1.
>   Выздоровление после тяжелой и длительной болезни. 2.Возобновление,
>   восстановление чего-л. старого, давно забытого. /em> Восходит к
>   Евангельской легенде о воскрешении Лазаря Иисусом. БМС 1998, 100.

https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/proverbs/15474/%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Воскрешение и воскресение в Библии, очевидно, стоит разделять. Наиболее распространенной трактовкой различия между ними является тот факт, что воскрешение – это активное действие, направленное на восстановление человека (иногда животного) из мертвых. Кто-то кого - воскрешает. Воскресение же является т. н. пассивным действием - сам воскрес. В соответствии с этой трактовкой принято считать, что в Библии воскрешение упоминается несколько раз, а вот воскресение – только единожды. Понятно, что во втором случае речь идет о событии, известном нам как Воскресение Христа.

Воскрешения Библия приписывает пророкам, апостолам и святым, а также самому Иисусу. Воскрешение Лазаря Христом (кстати, его описывает только Иоанн Богослов) произошло через четыре дня после смерти Лазаря от неизвестной болезни. http://funeral.by/religion/1054

Так что всё верно у автора - воскрешение Лазаря.

Answer (score 0):

Формально это должно подойти, поскольку *воскрешение* Лазаря - деяние Иисуса (*воскресить*), а не заслуга Лазаря (*воскреснуть*), хотя он "и вышел".

Comment: Саш, Лазаря воскресили, факт. Но и Лазарь *воскрес*! Ну какой из колокольчика *символ воскрешения*?..

Comment: Он не "символ воскрешения", а символизирует единичный исторический факт воскре**ш**ения Христом (который "есть воскре**с**ение", по его же словам, он его несёт, воскре**ш**ая) случайного смертного Лазаря. "Воскре**с**ение" же Лазаря приравнивало бы его _заслуженно_ воскресшему Христу.

Comment: Змей. С Лазарем произошло воскресение. И колокольчик символизирует етое воскресение, тока я доказать не можу. Мне б Людмилу сюда б.

Comment: Ещё лучше у г-на Невзорова спросить, он в семинариях учился некоторое время :) Не смог бы Лазарь воскреснуть сам, без вспоможения! Он воскрешённый, "вышел".

Comment: Кстати, гугл отказывается искать "воскресение Лазаря" (воскрешение предлагает)!

Comment: Ну да, боролись мы с етою гуглою... Она ж проблемы не сечёт.

Comment: Воскреснуть - практически возвратный глагол (**действие над самим собой**, типа _встрепенулся, ожил_), потому и неправда в случае воскрешённого Лазаря.