# Как оформить прямую речь, вклинившуюся (перебивом) в чужую прямую речь?

Tags: прямая-речь

> К этому моменту мы уже добрались до веранды, на которой нас поджидал
>   стол, накрытый скатертью, пока украшенный только пепельницей. «Я
>   предупредил, что вы курите! Курите! Курите! **– Дозволено пушенье! –
>   присоединился к нему стройный хор послушников.** – Курите!» Мне пришлось
>   спешно достать сигареты. «А теперь угощение!»

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда одна прямая речь перебивает другую, прибегают к абзацам, в месте перерыва ставят многоточие. Варианты:

К этому моменту мы уже добрались до веранды, на которой нас поджидал стол, накрытый скатертью, пока украшенный только пепельницей.

– Я предупредил, что вы курите! Курите! Курите!..

– Дозволено пушенье! – присоединился к нему стройный хор послушников.

– ... Курите!

Мне пришлось спешно достать сигареты.

– А теперь угощение!

**Или так:**

К этому моменту мы уже добрались до веранды, на которой нас поджидал стол, накрытый скатертью, пока украшенный только пепельницей.

«Я предупредил, что вы курите! Курите! Курите!..»

– Дозволено пушенье! – присоединился к нему стройный хор послушников.

« ... Курите!» Мне пришлось спешно достать сигареты.

– А теперь угощение!

**Если последняя реплика принадлежит этому же персонажу, то так:**

К этому моменту мы уже добрались до веранды, на которой нас поджидал стол, накрытый скатертью, пока украшенный только пепельницей.

«Я предупредил, что вы курите! Курите! Курите!..»

– Дозволено пушенье! – присоединился к нему стройный хор послушников.
« ... Курите!» Мне пришлось спешно достать сигареты.  «А теперь угощение!»

**Можно репликой оформить речь первого персонажа:**

К этому моменту мы уже добрались до веранды, на которой нас поджидал стол, накрытый скатертью, пока украшенный только пепельницей.

– Я предупредил, что вы курите! Курите! Курите!..

« Дозволено пушенье!» – присоединился к нему стройный хор послушников.

– Курите!

Мне пришлось спешно достать сигареты.

– А теперь угощение!

Answer (score 2):

**Современный вариант** (с курсивом):

К этому моменту мы уже добрались до веранды, на которой нас поджидал стол, накрытый скатертью, пока украшенный только пепельницей. «Я предупредил, что вы курите! Курите! Курите! — **«*Дозволено пушенье!» – присоединился к нему стройный хор послушников, и мне пришлось спешно достать сигареты***. — А теперь угощение!»

**Классика:**

К этому моменту мы уже добрались до веранды, на которой нас поджидал стол, накрытый скатертью, пока украшенный только пепельницей.

– Я предупредил, что вы курите! Курите! Курите!

«Дозволено пушенье!» – присоединился к нему стройный хор послушников.  Мне пришлось спешно достать сигареты.

— А теперь угощение!

Образцы

1) **Тургенев**

— Он похож на брата, — заметил Павел Петрович.

«На кого ж ему и походить?» — подумала Фенечка.

— Да, — продолжал, как бы говоря с самим собой, Павел Петрович, — несомненное сходство.

2) **Анна Матвеева** (современная проза)

Сатир неискренне уговаривал барменшу выйти из-за стойки, ***ну посиди с нами, Лен,*** но было очевидно — всё, что он мог получить от неё, давно получено, а интерес к этому «всему» — почти утерян.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Выбор варианта оформления прямой речи зависит от вида текста. Как мне кажется,  важно не **растягивать этот небольшой эпизод на всю страницу,**  но нужно выбрать **нечто компактное и в то же время емкое и выразительное,** именно в этом заключается мастерство писателя. Он как бы показывает нам одну и ту же ситуацию с позиций разных персонажей, это что-то вроде **искусства оператора при киносъёмке.**

И еще мне постоянно хочется сравнивать творчество литературное и художественное. В литературе тоже важна **перспектива,** если считать перспективой технику построения пространственных объектов на плоскости. **Потому что всё плоское и линейное представляется скучным и маловыразительным в любом искусстве.**

Answer (score 1):

К этому моменту мы уже добрались до веранды, на которой нас поджидал стол, накрытый скатертью, пока украшенный только пепельницей. «Я предупредил, что вы курите! Курите! Курите! («Дозволено пушенье!» - присоединился к нему стройный хор послушников. Мне пришлось спешно достать сигареты.) А теперь угощение!»

Answer (score 1):

В первом ответе я  привела два варианта оформления (классический и современный), но это только **для сравнения.** Разумеется, **классика не подходит для этого текста** и не стоит «размазывать» диалог на всю страницу.

Как известно, существует **три вида** текстов: повествование, описание и рассуждение. **Диалог важен в повествовании**, там он несет основную нагрузку для развития сюжета, изображения характера главных героев, в других же случаях **развернутую прямую речь заменяют пересказом** (косвенной речью).

Вернее сказать, **раньше заменяли**, но не сейчас. Пересказ скучен и невыразителен, а диалог конкретен, ярок, это живая речь, красочная деталь, как от нее отказаться!

**И писатели стараются включить диалог непосредственно в структуру описательного текста**, но сделать это не так просто: нет подходящих правил для оформления, да и художественного мастерства не всегда хватает.

Вот и приходится экспериментировать, использовать новые приемы и еще не нормированные формы, совмещая их с классическими правилами.